# Mozilla Observatory says I don't have a CSP, but I do

Tags: content-security-policy

the Mozilla Observatory tests my website and says that I do not have a Content Security Policy implemented, but I do.

See here: https://observatory.mozilla.org/analyze.html?host=mailpenny.com

Is there a misconfiguration in this?

My browser gives me CSP errors in development that I had to fix before the site worked, and I can see the following in my Headers when I do a `GET /` with Postman.

```
content-security-policy-report-only →default-src ânoneâ; connect-src 'self'; font-src 'self' fonts.gstatic.com; img-src 'self'; script-src 'self'; style-src 'unsafe-inline' 'self' fonts.googleapis.com,; report-uri https://payload.report-uri.io/r/default/csp/reportOnly
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: @TylerH is there a misconfiguration somewhere? Did you read the title? I've also added a link to the test, by the way.

Comment: I read the title and the question, and, while there's an implicit problem statement, there wasn't anything mentioned about what you wanted help with. Just trying to help clarify things for you :-)

Comment: @tylerH thank you I added one :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see two reasons that are likely part of the explanation:

- your CSP header contains invalid characters around "none" (as the value of `default-src`)
- it's a report-only header, so it doesn't actually protect your site, it only reports things that don't respect the said policy

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem, in my case I have in apache2 config:

```
Header set Content-Security-Policy  " script-src 'self' https://code.jquery.com http://ajax.googleapis.com 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval';font-src http://fonts.googleapis.com;   "
```

but Mozilla Observatory says:
**Content Security Policy (CSP) header cannot be parsed successfully**

Comment: try checking the actual header by loading your page using `curl -v`

Comment: after that I have added also
**Header set X-Content-Security-Policy**
everything works nice